# Change CSS properties directly in Angular 2+

Tags: javascript, angular, angular2-template

In jQuery, we can do

```
JQuery('.someStyle')
  .css({"background", "red"})
```

to directly change the CSS property in style.

In Angular 2+, we can use `[style.<property>]` to manipulate, is there an option to directly manipulate the style sheet?

Comment: Repeat after me: "Angular is not jQuery. Angular is not jQuery. Angular is not jQuery". There are dozens of reasons not to do this. You will end up with styles out of sync with the state of your system; among other issues, server-side rendering won't work. If you want to do this, it's a sign that you haven't made the mental shift from jQuery's imperative style to Angular's declarative style.

Comment: Yeah user9315861 , you are right. But jQuery is also much easier and better.

Comment: @Nick, When you come from jQuery to Angular, you need "rethink" your code in variables. jQuery change the DOM, Angular change the variables you're defined in .ts and this variables indicate how the DOM is showed. It's a bit step but singnificanty

Comment: @Eliseo. Yeah,I  just relearn this :-) But you have to write much,much more lines of code, for the same solution.

Answer (score 2):

Angular offer template reference variable like this. Here #textCont is a template variable which can be passed to component and it can be used to add styles

```
    <div #textCont> I wil change color on click<div>
<button type="button" (click)="changeColor(textCont)">Click</button>
```

In component

```
changeColor (elem){
    elem.style.color="red"
  }
```

[**DEMO**](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ypjqmu?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html)

Comment: also `<div [style.color]="color">`  and `<button (click)="color='red'">click</button>`

Answer (score 0):

Even with the jQuery snippet you posted you **don't manipulate the stylesheet**, only the CSS properties of the object representing the DOM element.

Why would you want to manipulate the stylesheet directly? You would have to modify it before the browser parses it - before it is sent from server to client. This is hardly desirable.

What you are probably looking for is just a way how to change styles of your DOM element dynamically.

There are many ways how to achieve that with Angular ranging from injecting `ElementRef` (object providing access to component's host element) to your component's constructor or using [`Renderer2`](https://angular.io/api/core/Renderer2) in order to change the styles directly on the DOM element, to templating (like the `[style.<property>]` you have mentioned) or even [Angular Animations](https://angular.io/guide/animations).

Answer (score 0):

Just fixed a small bug from @brk here. In Angular 13+ you may use:

```
<div #textCont> I wil change color on click</div>
<button type="button" (click)="changeColor(textCont)">Click</button>
```

And in Component more "strict typing"

```
changeColor(elem: { style: { color: string } }) {
  elem.style.color = 'red';
}
```